# Updates broke Mongo, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, updates, mongodb

I ran the software updater and now I can't use Mongo at all. My local server says it's connecting but any query gives me

```
'MongoError: exception: _extentManager.init failed: InternalError DataFile::openExisting - mmf.open failed'
```

and even running `show dbs` in the mongo shell gives me

```
listDatabases failed:{
"errmsg" : "exception: _extentManager.init failed: InternalError DataFile::openExisting - mmf.open failed",
"code" : 16966,
"ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
```

Answer (score 1):

I had Mongo 2.6.7 before the update. It broke and I couldn't find anything on google regarding the problem.

Solution:
I totally uninstalled Mongo and then reinstalled from the default Ubuntu repositories. It installs 2.4.9, but it works again with no problems.

Bonus:
It should preserve your existing databases. Always back things up if you can and I make no promises, but my databases were still there even after fully uninstalling and reinstalling.

Update: This was all with Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit. I switched to 64-bit and dl'ed Mongo again. Now it's giving me 3.0.3 from the default Ubuntu repo and everything works just fine. Idk if they maintain separate repos for each version or if they just updated recently.